# Can not set property InnerHTML of Null on my Ionic Application?

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework

In the code I am trying to show remaining time to generate a random code in the DOM.

```
   var count = setInterval(function () {
                    var date = new Date();
                    var currentSecond = date.getSeconds();
                    this.remaining = 60 - currentSecond;
                    document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML = this.remaining;
                    // alert('Time is running out ' + (i++));
                    temp.data.loadAll().then(result => {
                        temp.accounts = result;
                    });
                }, 1000);
```

And I am getting following error

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot set property innerHTML of null

Comment: Which clearly states that your `timer` element doesn't exist. Either it is completely missing or you are fetching it using wrong ID. Check your html if there is such element with id equal to `timer`.

Comment: <div class="col col-10">
                <div id="timer-box" id="timer">
                  <h4 id="timer"> {{this.remaining}} </h4>
                </div>
              </div>

Comment: where is this code present? in a liefecycle hook? and why manipulate the DOM like this?

Comment: You should not give id attribute to more than one HTML tag. In your code, it seems like div tag and h4 both are having same id (timer) which is not correct as per the HTML standards.

Comment: try to add this in ionViewDidLoad.

Comment: `<div id="timer-box" id="timer">` . **What?** An element can only have one id! `<div id="timer-box" id="timer"> <h4 id="timer">` **What?** So now not only do we have an element with two ids, we have at least two elements with the same id. No wonder you are getting weird results. Fix these issues first.

Answer (score 0):

No need to assign `setInterval` to any variable simply call it into `constructor` or `ngOnInit` life cycle hook like this

```
constructor() {
    setInterval(() => {
      var date = new Date();
      var currentSecond = date.getSeconds();
      this.remaining = 60 - currentSecond;
      document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML = this.remaining;
      // alert('Time is running out ' + (i++));
      temp.data.loadAll().then(result => {
          temp.accounts = result;
      });
  }, 1000);
  }
```

and Here is HTML you provided

```
<div class="col col-10"> 
      <div id="timer-box" id="timer"> 
         <h4 id="timer"> {{remaining}} </h4> 
      </div>
</div>
```

Here is [working example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xntlyv?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts)

Also

- Replace `function(){..}` with arrow function to maintain scope like I did in my answer.
- No need to use `this` in HTML part to bind value.

Comment: But as shown in working example (https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xntlyv?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts) here , everything is working fine. There must be error coming from somewhere else